# I am having trouble with Bresenham's algorithm

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

It only works when slope is between 0 and 1. i'm not sure where to go from here. thanks for your help! This method reads in two points and draws the line between them using bresenhams algo. I don't know where to go to optimize it for all lines. thanks for your help.

```
void Bresenhams(int x1, int y1, int xk, int yk)
    {
        int deltaX = xk - x1;
        int deltaY = yk - y1;
        int error = 0;
        int y = y1;
        int x = x1;
        int doubleDeltaX = 2 * deltaX;
        bool steep = Math.Abs(yk - y1) > Math.Abs(xk - x1);



        canvas.SetPixel(x1, y1, Color.Black);

        if (!steep)
        {
            for (int i = x1 + 1; i <= xk; i++)
            {

                if (x1 > xk)
                {
                    int temp = x1;
                    x1 = xk;
                    xk = temp;

                    temp = y1;
                    y1 = yk;
                    yk = temp;

                }

                error = error + deltaY;
                if (error > deltaX)
                {
                    y++;
                    error -= doubleDeltaX;
                }
                canvas.SetPixel(i, y, Color.Black);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = y1 + 1; i <= yk; i++)
            {

                if (y1 > yk)
                {
                    int temp = x1;
                    x1 = xk;
                    xk = temp;

                    temp = y1;
                    y1 = yk;
                    yk = temp;
                }

                error = error + deltaY;
                if (error > deltaY)
                {
                    y++;
                    error -= doubleDeltaX;
                }
                canvas.SetPixel(x, i, Color.Black);
            }
        }

        pictureBox1.Image = canvas;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide a circle into 8 parts.  You can run Bresenham over one octant and draw all 8 at the same time.  For center at 0,0:

```
   0-45 x,y
  45-90 y,x
 90-135 -y,x
135-180 -x,y
180-225 -x,-y
225-270 -y,-x
270-315 y,-x
315-360 x,-y
```